# Computed Property causes array and object mutation

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to pass data to a v-select dropdown.
This of course works:

```
computed: {
  itemDropdown() {
    const menuItems = {
        id: "1",
        name: "Joe"
      }
    return menuItems;
  }
}
```

But when I try:

```
computed: {
  itemDropdown() {
      const newArray = [...this.data.originalItems];
      newArray.map(item => {
        item.name = "myCoolNewName";
      });
      return newArray;
  }
}
```

It mutates the original array.
I have also tried copying the object:

```
computed: {
  itemDropdown() {
      const newObj = { ...this.data };
      newObj.items.map(item => {
        item.name = "myCoolNewName";
      });
      return newObj;
  }
}
```

Not sure what I’m missing, but wondering if there is a work around. Thanks for any help :slight_smile:

Comment: I have tried splice also.

Comment: For clarification, in your first code block, i assume that menuItems is supposed to be an array of objects and not just an object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the map array method wrong.

The first thing you need to know, is that the map method returns a **new** array, so you have to either return the result of your map function or save it in a variable, otherwise you will just be looping through your array without ever saving it anywhere.

Another thing is about how you use the map method.
Here I have made an example of how it should work with your code:

```js
computed: {
  itemDropdown() {
      return this.data.originalItems.map(item => {
        return {
          name: "myCoolNewName"
        }
      });
  }
}
```

The big difference you should notice, is that inside the map function, we have to return what we want each object to look like, after we have gone through it. We want it to give us the object back, but make some changes to it, so we have to actually return an object and change what we want in that.

What you were doing before, was refering to the item in the old array, and assigning it a new value, instead of returning a new object with your changes.

You can read about the array.map method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: Thanks this helps, `return { name: "myCoolNewName" }` was the right way to do it 

Comment: You're welcome. If that solves your problem you should mark my answer as correct so that others can see that your issue is resolved. :)